# Executando texto como código no VBA

Tags: string, microsoft-excel, vba, visual-basic-6

O código abaixo calcula a fórmula contida na variável Texto (String):

```
Private Sub CalculeFormulaNoTexto()

Dim Texto As String

Texto = "= 90 / 3 + 7 + COS(0) + 1/7"

' A variável Texto recebe a fórmula que quero calcular
' Observe que o primeiro caractere é o sinal de igual "='
' Sem ele o cálculo não ocorre

' Coloco o conteúdo de Texto na célula A1
Cells(1, 1) = Texto

'Pego o resultado do cálculo obtido na célula A1
Resultado = Cells(1, 1)

'Apresento o resultado
MsgBox Texto & " = " & Resultado

End Sub
```

**Algumas observações:**

*Verifique o conteúdo da **célula A1** na planilha*, ela está com a fórmula do jeito que ficaria se fosse digitada na própria célula

A variável "**Resultado**" pode ser usada para outros cálculos, pois ela armazenou o **valor resultante que está na célula**

**PROBLEMA**

Fiz outros testes e nem todos tiveram sucesso

Por exemplo, para:

```
Texto = "= 9 + 2 * COS(3*PI()/2) + ARRED(1/7;4)"
```

Surgirá um erro na célula e o código apresentará erro também (neste caso não é por causa da função ARRED, use ela em uma equação menor e funcionará)

**SURPRESA**

Se você for na célula com erro ("A1") e der **F2 para editar e ENTER**, o cálculo será feito corretamente

**DÚVIDA**

Qual o motivo do erro e como resolver este problema de executar um texto dentro do código do VBA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O seu Excel obviamente está em Português, uma vez que você está usando a função `ARRED` para **arred**ondar um resultado e o ponto-e-vírgula (`;`) como separador de parâmetros. Por isso, naturalmente, funciona se você digitar a fórmula diretamente numa célula do Excel.

Essa função `ARRED` se chama `ROUND` no Excel original em Inglês. Esse recurso de tradução de funções é algo que pode ser bacana para usuários inexperientes (porque eles escrevem as funções no idioma nativo). Mas é um problemão para o tipo de coisa que você quer fazer, pois o VBA *só aceita as funções escritas em inglês*.

Assim, experimente escrever no seu código o seguinte:

```
Texto = "= 9 + 2 * COS(3*PI()/2) + ROUND(1/7,4)"
```

Note que eu troquei a função `ARRED` por `ROUND` e troquei o ponto-e-vírgula (`;`) por vírgula (`,`) para separar o parâmetro `1/7` do parâmetro `4`. (É que em inglês a vírgula é o separador de milhar e o ponto é o separador de decimal, então não tem como confundir na separação de parâmetros; como em português confunde, usa-se o ponto-e-vírgula para separar parâmetros).

Naturalmente, o Excel vai fazer a "tradução" automaticamente pra você, então se você for até a célula e apertar F2 vai vê-la traduzida. Infelizmente, só tem esse jeito de fazer funcionar, e você vai ter que consultar a documentação em inglês para descobrir os nomes originais das funções que utilizar.

Comment: Funcionou, grato.

Comment: Por nada. Se a resposta foi útil,  por favor considere aceitá-la. ;)

Comment: Está aceita não?

Comment: Sim, agora está. :)

Comment: Só queria agradecer o Luiz Vieira por ter respondido a pergunta a cima, MUITO OBRIGADO, eu já estava ficando doido