# Alterar valores de célula excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macro

Preciso através de MACRO alterar o valor de uma célula no excel.

Um campo do tipo contábil tem o seguinte valor: R$15,326685459.

Preciso alterar o a célula automaticamente para que fique: R$15,32000000000.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você precisa dos números 0 ao fim? Ou pode ser arredondado e ficaria `R$15,33`? Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101003/75104) com a função `arred` ou `round`

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar essa fórmula em vez de uma macro:

```
inglês
=TEXT(ROUND(A1,2),"0.00000000000")
Portuguese
=TEXTO(ARRED(A1,2),"0.00000000000")
```